# Pass through authentication from Openldap to Openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap, saslauthd

I am looking for a method to setup a Pass Through Authentication (PTA) between 2 openldap instances. All what I found is that is is possible to have this feature between an openldap instance to which clients are connected and an Active Directory as a backend with SASL. Technically speaking, is this supported by openldap to setup a PTA between 2 openldap instances ?

Comment: You want to have second instance with the same data? Or some network rules passing trough some data?

Comment: Second instance, not exactly with the same DIT but for users that connects to openLDAP1 the password verification is sent to openldap2 (which is the main openldap of the company). OpenLdap1 should never register userPassword attribute. I am not really looking for a synchro. procedure but rather a secure way to leave the password verification to openldap2 while the user object exists in both openldap1 and openldap2 (same uid).